# Not getting the right output

Tags: java, inheritance, tostring

Probably just a small error, but I cant seem to find it anywhere. When I run the program, it prints "After depositing $100: Savings Account:, also my withdraw class seems not to be working, as the balance after withdrawing money does not change.

```
public class CheckingandSavings 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Savings savings = new Savings(1001,1000.0);
        Checking checking = new Checking(1002, 2000.0);

        System.out.println("At the beginning: " + savings);
        savings.deposit(100);
        System.out.println("After depositing $100: " + savings);
        savings.withdraw(500);
        System.out.println("After withdrawing $500: " + savings);

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("At the beginning: " + checking);
        checking.deposit(100);
        System.out.println("After depositing $100: " + checking);
        checking.withdraw(500);
        System.out.println("After withdrawing $500: " + checking);
    }
}

public class Account {

    private int accountNumber;
    private double accountBalance;

    //The Two-Arg Constructor
    public Account(int accountNumber, double accountBalance)
    {
        setAccountBalance(accountBalance);
        setAccountNumber(accountNumber);
    }

    //Getter for accountNumber
    public int getAccountNumber()
    {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    //Setter for accountNumber
    public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber)
    {
        if (accountNumber >= 0)
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    //Getter for accountBalance
    public double getAccountBalance()
    {
        return accountBalance;
    }

    //Setter for accountBalance
    public void setAccountBalance(double accountBalance)
    {
        if (accountNumber >= 0)
            this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
    }

    //Deposit to accountBalance
    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        if (amount > 0)
            this.accountBalance += amount;
    }

    //Withdraw from accountBalance
    public double withdraw(double amount)
    {
        if (amount > 0 || amount > this.accountBalance)
            return 0;

        this.accountBalance -= amount;
        return this.;
    }

    //Returns a string of the instance data
    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "";
        result += "Account Number: " + this.accountNumber;
        result += "\nAccount Balance: $" + String.format("%.2f", this.accountBalance);
        return result;
    }
}

public class Savings extends Account {

    //The two-arg constructor
    public Savings(int accountNumber, double accountBalance)
    {
        super(accountNumber, accountBalance);
    }

    //Returns a string of the instance data
    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "";
        result += "Savings Account: \n" + super.toString();
        return result;
    }
}

public class Checking extends Account {


    //The two-arg constructor
    public Checking(int accountNumber, double accountBalance)
    {
        super(accountNumber,accountBalance);
    }

    //Returns a string of the instance data
    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        result += "Checking Account: \n" + super.toString();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to just post the relevant code, and format it a bit better ;-)

Comment: Or just debug it and fix it yourself...

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at your withdraw method:

```
//Withdraw from accountBalance
public double withdraw(double amount)
{
    if (amount > 0 || amount > this.accountBalance) //This needs to be &&
        return 0;

    this.accountBalance -= amount;
    return this.; //I am assuming you meant this to be this.accountBalance?
}
```

You are saying if the amount you want to withdraw is greater than 0 OR it is greater than your account balance, return 0. I think you want to say AND so instead put `amount > 0 && amount > this.accountBalance`

Also, you should be returning `this.accountBalance`.

Lastly, you should really put the `@Override` annotation above your `toString` methods. This lets the compiler know you are overriding a parents method.